# No se puede pasar parámetros a una vista

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Tengo el siguiente listado de clientes, con dos botones: Modificar y Editar.

Cuando aprieto, por ejemplo en Modificar, sé que va a `http://localhost:1173/DetalleCliente?id=1`, pero me dice "No se encuentra el recurso."

controlador:

```
using Ejercicio03.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Ejercicio03.Controllers
{
    public class ClienteController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Cliente

        // BIENVENIDO
        public ActionResult Bienvenido()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // LISTADO DE CLIENTES
        public ActionResult Todos()
        {
            ClienteServicio cs = new ClienteServicio();
            var listado = cs.mostrarCliente();

            return View(listado);
        }

        // ALTA CLIENTE
        public ActionResult AltaCliente()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]  // RECIBE LOS DATOS DE LA VISTA "AltaCliente".
        public ActionResult AltaCliente(Cliente c)
        {

            ClienteServicio cs = new ClienteServicio(c.id, c.nombre, c.apellido);

            return View("Bienvenido"); // Retorna a la vista "Bienvenido"
        }

        // MOSTRAR DETALLE CLIENTE
        public ActionResult DetalleCliente()
        {
            ClienteServicio cs = new ClienteServicio();
            var detalle = cs.mostrarCliente();

            return View(detalle);
        }

        // EDITAR CLIENTE
        public ActionResult EditarCliente()
        {
            ClienteServicio cs = new ClienteServicio();
            var cli = cs.mostrarCliente();

            return View(cli);
        }

      /*  [HttpPost]  // RECIBE LOS DATOS DE LA VISTA "EditarCliente".
        public ActionResult EditarClienteProc(Cliente c)
        {
            ClienteServicio cs = new ClienteServicio(c.id, c.nombre, c.apellido);
            return View("Bienvenido");

        }
        */

    }
}
```

Cliente.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Ejercicio03.Models
{
    public class Cliente
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string nombre { get; set; }
        public string apellido { get; set; }

    }
}
```

ClienteServicio.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Ejercicio03.Models
{
    public class ClienteServicio
    {
        // INSTANCIAMOS 
        public static List<Cliente> lista = new List<Cliente>();

        // CONSTRUCTOR SIN PARAMETROS
        public ClienteServicio()
        {
            // INICIALIZAMOS
            if (lista.Count == 0)
            {
                this.altaCliente(1, "Julian", "Butron");
                this.altaCliente(2, "Pedro", "Picapiedra");
                this.altaCliente(3, "Pablo", "Marmol");
            }
        }

        // CONSTRUCTOR CON PARAMETROS
        public ClienteServicio(int id, string nombre, string apellido)
        {
            this.altaCliente(id, nombre, apellido);
        }

        // GETTER: MOSTRAR LISTA
        public List<Cliente> mostrarCliente()
        {
            return lista;
        }

        // SETTER: ESTABLECER CLIENTE
        public void altaCliente(int id, string nombre, string apellido)
        {
           lista.Add(new Cliente() { id = id, nombre = nombre, apellido = apellido });
        }

    }
}
```

Vista todos

```
    @Model Ejercicio03.Models.Cliente 

    @{
        Layout = null;
    }

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <title>Todos</title>
    </head>
    <body style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica">

        <a href="Bienvenido"><input type="button" value="Volver" style="margin-left:635px;margin-top:18px;"/></a>

        <div style="width:600px;margin:auto;margin-top:-45px;background-color:#DD0611;color:white;">      

            <h2 style="padding-top:20px;text-align:center;">CLIENTES</h2>

            <a href="AltaCliente"><input type="button" value="Nuevo Cliente" style="margin: 0 0 6px 6px;padding:4px;background-color:#1DAE46;color:white;"/></a>

        </div>

        <table align="center" width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ECEBEB" padding="10px">
            <tr>
                <th style="padding:3px;border-bottom: 1px solid #fff">Id</th>
                <th style="padding:3px;border-bottom: 1px solid #fff">Nombre</th>
                <th style="padding:3px;border-bottom: 1px solid #fff">Apellido</th>
                <th colspan='2' style="padding:3px;border-bottom: 1px solid #fff">Operaciones</th>

            </tr>

            @foreach (Ejercicio03.Models.Cliente c in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align:center;padding:3px;border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;">@c.id</td>
                    <td style="text-align:center;padding:3px;border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;">@c.nombre</td>
                     <td style="text-align:center;padding:3px;border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;">@c.apellido</td>
                    <td style="text-align:center;padding:3px;border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;"><a href="DetalleCliente?id=@c.id"><input type="button" value="Mostrar" /></a></td>
                    <td style="text-align:center;padding:3px;border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;"><a href="EditarCliente?id=@c.id"><input type="button" value="Editar" /></a></td>
                </tr>
            }

        </table>
    </body>
    </html>

vista detallecliente
@Model Ejercicio03.Models.Cliente

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>DetalleCliente</title>
</head>
<body style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica">

    <div style="width:600px;margin:auto;margin-top:40px;padding:5px;background-color:#DD0611;color:white;box-sizing: border-box;">
        <h2 style="text-align:center;">Cliente</h2>
    </div>

    <table align="center" width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ECEBEB" ;margin="0" ;padding="0" ;>      
        <tr>
            <th style="padding:3px;border-bottom: 1px solid #fff">Id</th>
            <th style="padding:3px;border-bottom: 1px solid #fff">Nombre</th>
            <th style="padding:3px;border-bottom: 1px solid #fff">Apellido</th>
        </tr>

         @foreach (Ejercicio03.Models.Cliente c in Model)
        {
            if (c.id == Convert.ToInt16(Request["id"]))
            {
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align:center;padding:5px;border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;">@c.id</td>
                    <td style="text-align:center;padding:5px;border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;">@c.nombre</td>
                    <td style="text-align:center;padding:5px;border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;">@c.apellido</td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                     <td colspan='3' style="text-align:center;padding:10px;border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;"><a href="Bienvenido"><input type="button" value="SALIR" /></a></td>
                 </tr>
            }
        }
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

el programa arranca de la vista Todos y se debe redirigir a la vista DetalleCliente. Que está mal? Tambien con la opción Editar pasa lo mismo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esto se debe a que en la URL se debe indicar el `Controller` y el `Action` a donde desees que llegue la petición. Modifica el link para editar el cliente para que quede de la siguiente forma:

```
<a href=@Url.Action("EditarCliente", "Cliente", new { idCliente = c.id });>
```

La línea completa quedaría así:

```
<td style="text-align:center;padding:3px;border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;"><a href=@Url.Action("EditarCliente", "Cliente", new { idCliente = c.id });><input type="button" value="Editar" /></a></td>
```

En el `Controller` debes recibir el `Id` del cliente que desees editar:

```
public ActionResult EditarCliente(int idCliente)
{
    //Operaciones a base de datos y lógica para la edición del cliente
}
```

Comment: ahora me dice : "El diccionario de parámetros contiene una entrada NULL para el parámetro 'idCliente' del tipo que no acepta valores NULL 'System.Int32' del método 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult EditarCliente(Int32)' en 'Ejercicio03.Controllers.ClienteController'. Un parámetro opcional debe ser un tipo de referencia, un tipo que acepte valores NULL o debe declararse como parámetro opcional.
Nombre del parámetro: parameters"

Comment: sin pasarle el int idCliente funciona, Ahora debo corregir la lógica de negocio. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Efectivamente, estás intentando cargar algo desde la nada. Como piensas que el controlador va a cargar ese valor si la acción del controlador no recibe nada. Además no veo por ningún lado que tipo de verbo utilizarás para hacer esa petición que obviamente es **[HttpGet]**.